# jQuery slideToggle jumps back

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I use slideToggle for a simple accordion, but when clicked on the opened accordion to close, it closes and than jumps back to opened.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
    <ul class="footer-menu">  
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div>  
<div>
    <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
    <ul class="footer-menu"> 
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
    <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.footer-menu').hide();
$('.footer-title').click(function(){
    $('.footer-menu').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.footer-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/eriktailor/pen/bGowxwg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the next element where the click event has occurred is visible or not depending on this move `$('.footer-menu').slideUp();` line inside if condition.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$('.footer-menu').hide();
$('.footer-title').click(function() {
  var isOpen = $(this).next('.footer-menu').is(":visible"); //check if the next elemnt is visible (means we are closing it)
  if (!isOpen) {
    $('.footer-menu').slideUp();
  }
  $(this).next('.footer-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
  <ul class="footer-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
  <ul class="footer-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="footer-title">First title</h2>
  <ul class="footer-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```